# Xamarin Maps/Google Maps place custom Pin on centre point

Tags: c#, xamarin, maps, pins

I'm trying to place the centre of a custom pin onto my map. Xamarin and GoogleMaps nuget packages automatically place the bottom centre of the pin on the Location (lat/long) property.

[Standard Pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfs4S.png)

I want to place the centre of my marker on the location property, like so:

[Centred Pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl8mM.png)

I've tried modifying the Pin Location value based on the zoom level of the map, making the image larger (with 1/3 whitespace above), but all that does is make my markers too big to use as the OnTapEvent covers a large area.

Ideally I'd just offset the x,y position of the marker to the centre, but due to the fact you can zoom in and out of a map I'm unfamiliar with the logic (therefore can no code to show).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not clear that what is your problem, you want to put **X** in your custom pin, but having some problems when making the image larger? You use custom render to [customize a Map Pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin) ?

Comment: No the x is where I want it placed on the map. I want the centre of the pin to be the 0,0 coordinate of the image, not the 0.5/0 as standard pins are

Comment: If you still have problem, please provide one simple sample, help to reproduce your problem.